# imageView layout_height android

Tags: android

My problem is my `imageView01` appears too large, and I can't read what it says in the picture. I want it to be the right height.

You can see what I mean in the images below:

[image: http://imageshack.com/a/img189/6051/3z8p.jpg]

[image: http://imageshack.com/a/img31/2001/7mcl.jpg]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              >


    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/examplegallery" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTextDescription"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
         </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: change scaletype to this android:scaleType="matrix"  then actual image appears..

Answer (score 0):

use `android:scaleType="centerInside"` this value for scale type. It will Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding). The image is then centered in the view.

```
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />
```

Answer (score 0):

copy this xml instead of your xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              >


    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/examplegallery" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTextDescription"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
         </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```